# Save and Autofill Data in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, autofill

I have a web view where the user can enter their email and password. I'm wanting to know how I could save the entered values and autofill the fields when the user returns to the web view during future uses..

Comment: This doesn't sound dangerous at all... Is your webview pointing to a bank website? Does your app send the username / password to a server that you control?

Comment: Yes, it is a server and website under my control.

Comment: Looking for any autofill capability within a UIWebView or WKWebView in a native app... looks like it won't happen except if you have proven your app is associated with a specific URL.  And it appears that URLs must be defined at the time of submitting to the App Store, rather than being changed on the fly after updating the app.  Can anyone confirm this?